# Multiple networks with DHCP prioritizing one

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I'm trying to setup a client machine connected to two networks, both going out to the internet.

Both networks, eth0 and vlan (eth0.8) should use DHCP.

I want to use all the domain-name-servers, domain-search etc from interface eth0.
I want to get IP + subnet for eth0.8, but ignore all other responses such as domain-name-servers.

It seems no matter what I do, the domain-name-server and search path from eth0.8 are added to resolv.conf

e.g. /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
interface "eth0" {
    request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
}

interface "eth0.8" {
    request subnet-mask, broadcast-address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may just be to make the ip of eth0.2 static. Is that feasable in your setup?

Comment: I prefer not to as there are quite a few clients I need to setup in this way.

Comment: interface "eth0.8"

I'm guessing that's a typo? Should it be 0.2?

Comment: its a typo in the description, i'll update